# Signalr on Azure Mobile Services or Web Roles

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-mobile-services

I am developing a mobile application that makes extensive and continuous use of SignalR to communicate to a SignalR service.

I have previously assumed that I would use a Web Role to host the service, and then add more Web Roles backed by a backplane of Service Bus or Redis as and when the service needs to scale out. Using a Web Role would also allow me to significantly scale up if I wanted to avoid possible latency issues with the backplane.

However when I compare the pricing of the Web Role to Azure Mobile Services it appears that the Mobile Services may be cheaper.

So can Mobile Services be used instead?
And if so what are the pros and cons of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are close to rolling out an update to Azure Mobile Services .NET backend which comes with some neat integration with SignalR built in. I'll be posting a blog on it on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/ (and of course on twitter @frystyk) when it's there and how to use it.

Henrik

Comment: That's great - I look forward to seeing it! Will your post also look at the pros and cons of using it in Mobile Services against a Web Role?

Comment: Henrik's blog post is at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/30/realtime-with-signalr-and-azure-mobile-net-backend.aspx

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer because it provides excellent information on how to use SignalR in Mobile Services, however I still do not really know the pros and cons of this compared to using a Web Role.